# sudo is removed

Tags: apt

I am new to Ubuntu operating system. My sudo is not working in my laptop.
And system settings are disable and Ubuntu software center is disappear
when I type  sudo on my terminal.

```
~$ sudo
The program 'sudo' can be found in the following packages:
 * sudo
 * sudo-ldap
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

then I surf web  find out `apt-get install sudo`
for my problem

```
~$ apt-get install sudo

E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

then copy and paste for above issues file and lock to adminstration directory

```
:~$ ps -e | grep -e apt -e adept | grep -v grep
~$ rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

then show the

```
ps -e | grep -e apt -e adept | grep -v grep
venki@venki-Inspiron-3558:~$ rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock 
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file ‘/var/lib/dpkg/lock’?
```

the cursor will not respond 
please help me anyone

Answer (score 3):

You can enter in single user mode from the [grub menu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting) by selecting the recovery mode. Drop to a bash shell and you will have `root` acces. This will install `sudo` for you ...

```
 apt-get install sudo
```

There is more though: `gksu` is a dependency of it. Simplest may be to do ...

```
 apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

to get that back (and any other software that got nuked when you removed `sudo`).

Comment: You beat me to it :( But don't you have to enable network access to be able to reinstall it?

Comment: @AndroidDev hmm that might be possible. grub rescue might be easier :)

Comment: That's my point. I think you have to select the "enable networking" item in recovery mode, then drop to root shell... could be wrong though...

Comment: Or use the dvd/usb as a repo. I am not going to delete sudo on my system to find out ;-)

Comment: Yes you will need to enable networking if the .deb does not just happen to be still in /var/cache/apt/archives/ - doing so has the side effect of remounting the root filesystem in rw mode. If the .deb is available locally, then the filesystem will still need to be remounted e.g. `mount -o remount,rw /` in order for the installation to proceed, I think